# Finding $\prod\limits_{k=0}^n(1+0.5^{2^k})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Find the product $$\prod_{k=0}^n(1+0.5^{2^k})$$

I tried but I couldn't, any help?

Comment: Do you mean the last term is $0.5^{2^n}$?

Comment: Yes, If you could edit the post I'll appreciate it

Comment: Please show what you tried before asking for help.

Comment: Multiply by $1-0.5$ and watch things collapse.

Answer (score 8):

From 
$$
\left(1-x^{2^k} \right)\left(1+x^{2^k} \right)=\left(1-x^{2^{k+1}} \right)
$$ you deduce, for $x^{2^k} \neq 1$,
$$
\left(1+x^{2^k} \right)=\frac{\left(1-x^{2^{k+1}} \right)}{\left(1-x^{2^k} \right)}
$$ and when multiplying **factors telescope** giving

> $$
> \prod_{k=0}^n\left(1+x^{2^k} \right)=\prod_{k=0}^n\frac{\left(1-x^{2^{k+1}} \right)}{\left(1-x^{2^k} \right)}=\frac{1-x^{2^{n+1}} }{1-x }.
> $$

Then put $x:=0.5$ to get the desired result.

Comment: Did you mean that equals to $2$?

Comment: @maya If you consider the **finite** product it is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{1-0.5^{2^{n+1}} }{0.5}=2\left( 1-0.5^{2^{n+1}}\right)$. Now if you let $n \to +\infty$, then the **infinite** product is equal to $2$. Thanks!

Comment: No, $n$ is not goes to infinity, what the result then ????

Comment: Splendid answer!

Comment: @maya Thus the answer is just: $$\prod_{k=0}^n\left(1+0.5^{2^k} \right)=2\left(1-0.5^{2^{n+1}} \right) .$$